# How to add MVC 4 into VS 2015

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2015

I'm new to MVC and I'm trying to follow an old exercise, I'm following every steps carefully since I'm not familiar what to expect yet, but I'm stuck with creating a project because I'm not seeing the MVC 4 template, please tell me how to get this so I can move on.

This is the expected result.

[image]

This is what I'm getting.

[image]

Comment: The next step in your screenshot will ask you which template, you'll choose MVC. But this installs version 5. You could try to downgrade the package with NuGet but I'm sure there's a whole bunch of other dependency changes to make. You can also search the Online templates on the same screen you show above. I don't find version 5 much different than version 4. Have you tried the exercise with the newer MVC?

Comment: That is what I initially did, but for some reason the project is not getting created, it's like nothing is loading. Anyway your answer is logically right, maybe I'm just missing something in the setup.